# A challenge: put a RESPONSIVE Web App Form made with GAS into a HTML Page

Tags: google-apps-script

I ask you for help because I have had a problem for some time that I cannot solve.
I have a simple form built through a web app and need to embed this form into a web page via an IFRAME.
I can do this, of course, by adding setXFrameOptionsMode (HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).

Problem is, I can't find a way to make it **responsive**.

I learned that there are two approaches to make an IFRAME responsive. The first one, [described here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_iframes.asp), is to make use of the aspect ratio. It may work for a video, but not for a form with text, the height of which varies together with the viewport.
Then I found [this project](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) and found that you can use postmessage to dynamically set the height of the IFRAME.

It works smoothly in normal circumstances, but [as I described here](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/issues/886) it doesn't work with Google Apps Script because the IFRAME generated by GAS is nested inside two other IFRAMES.

At this point my question is: **is there a solution to this problem?** Do we have to accept it is NOT possible to embed a responsive IFRAME made with GAS into web pages?

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output-meta-tag) might help.

Comment: I'm already using the method addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')  with my script. And it renders perfectly except for iframe... You can take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/nuanda74/o6xdte9f/5/

Comment: There may some hack but there is no "proper" way to do what you want. Simply put, because that would mean that the content of each page would need to communicate with each other, which is not possible due to CORS. But if you already have a site, you must have the ability to host your own web pages, correct?